# Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row

Tags: mysql, sql

Делаю свой первый сайт и постоянно выходит вот такая ошибка:

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 43 in index.php on line 10
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in index.php on line 12
```

Как это можно использовать для проведения SQL-инъекции?

Задача абсолютно учебная и не несёт никаких незаконных целей

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"У меня ошибка с сообщением о том, что мой код не работает. Как ее можно использовать для вторжения?"
Конкретно ошибку - никак. Она формируется после запроса (и происходит на стороне php, а не mysql), а инъекция происходит до.